# Escaping characters on SQL Update (Replace)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a SQL UPDATE with REPLACE to insert a system variable into a text field. The issue I am having is, the system variable contains [ and ] and must be included into the UPDATE.

I have found many articles on this subject, but none of the solutions work when it involves a REPLACE.

```
UPDATE S_DETAIL 
SET TITLE = replace(TITLE,' | ',' for #[A_EMPLOYEE.DISPLAY_NAME]# | ')  
WHERE TYPE_ID = 18 AND 
      TITLE like '% | %'
```

I need to escape the brackets. so the TITLE field reads as:

```
'for #[A_EMPLOYEE.DISPLAY_NAME]#'
```

Comment: Have you tried just doing a concat with + signs? replace(TITLE,' | ',' for ['+A_EMPLOYEE.DISPLAY_NAME+'] | ')? I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do? you shouldn't need to escape anything

Comment: That doesn't work. I need to escape the brakets as SQL does not see it as text. The brackets needs to be in the test stored in the field. If I were to query this field, the value would literally be "for #[A_EMPLOYEE.DISPLAY_NAME]#" without the quotes

Comment: What do you mean the brackets need to be escaped? There is nothing in your code here that needs to be escaped at all.

Comment: If I run the query as is, I get an error on [

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The query you have posted [runs as written without errors](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab5b0/1).

Comment: You don't need to escape your brackets in you REPLACE statement. You have an issue somewhere else, hence @EricBrandt's comment.